# Wordpress plugin won't show on some themes

Tags: plugins, themes

I have made a wordpress plugin following standard wordpress tutorials. This plugin add a file upload to the comment form by using simply this function:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', array(&$this, 'add_to_comment_form') );
```

. But when I activate some themes it won't show on the comment form.

Any Help how to make it show on comment form?

Comment: Are those themes using `comments_template` rather than `comment_form` to display the form?

Comment: Sorry I am new to wordpress I don't know exactly how to find it, but it has inside a comments.php file.

Comment: I see a comments_template() inside single.php

Comment: I think it is using comment_form because I see it in the comments.php: `<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>`

Comment: What software do you use to edit your code? It should be able to perform a global search in all your theme files...

Comment: eclipse. But please just tell me how to understand if it using template form or comment form, and how to act in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

`comment_form_logged_in_after` action hook was added to WordPress When [**`comment_form()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) was introduced at version 3.0.

So the themes where your plugin doesn't work  are probably outdated themes that don't use `comment_form`.

Comment: this is wordpress 3.2

Comment: It's not about the version of WordPress, it's about the function the theme uses to display the comment form. The old way didn't use the action that you're hooking to.

Comment: Mrwweb is correct and as i posted the themes are out dated not the WordPress version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding these actions to comments.php of the theme:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
//...................theme code
<?php do_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', $comment_author, $user_identity );  ?>
```

and

```
do_action( 'comment_form_after_fields' );
```

Hope this help someone and also for theme makers